# SOQL - Find parent if none of parent's children have an attribute

Tags: soql

An `Account` has many `Contacts`.  Every `Contact` has the boolean attribute `Account_Owner__c`.

I need to construct a SOQL query that finds all `Accounts` where the `Account` has no `Contacts` where `Account_Owner__c = true`.

Things I have tried:

(1) Finding all `Accounts` that have at least one `Contact` where `Account_Owner__c = true`, extracting the `Ids` of those accounts, then inserting those ids into a second querystring.  This throws a broken pipe error:

```
accts = client.query("select Id from Account where Id in (select 
AccountId from Contact where Contact.Account_Owner__c = true)")

ids = accts.map { |a| a.id }.join(',')

result = client.query("select Id from Account where Id not in #{ids}")
```

(2) This querystring, which returns nil:

```
client.query("select Id, Name from Account where Id not in (select 
AccountId from Contact where Contact.Account_Owner__c = true)")
```

(3) This querystring, which throws the error 'The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object type':

```
client.query("select Id, Name, Career_Plug_Account_Id__c from Account 
where Id not in (select Id from Account where Id in (select AccountId 
from Contact where Contact.Account_Owner__c = true))")
```

I've read the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com) and [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm?search_text=not%20in), but suspect I am missing or misunderstanding something.

Comment: (2) is what I would consider the correct approach. Is that Ruby that you're using? Have you tried executing this query directly through the Developer Console to see if you can separate the query issue from any connection/library issues?

Comment: @DavidReed, I have not tried that (the Salesforce ecosystem is new to me).  I'll play around in the Console now that I know it exists!

Comment: Also, do you have an order-of-magnitude sense of how many records you have? The query certainly could be timing out. Using the Query Plan tool in Developer Console could help pinpoint any performance issues.

Comment: I think we can agree number 2 is your best option. I'd like to see the question rephrased to explain what you're trying to do with query #2, remove the other queries and then go into more detail as to what the issue with query number 2 is so we can help you fix that issue.

Comment: @DavidReed It looks like this was indeed a connection or library problem, as running (2) in the Developer Console produces what appear to be the correct results.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great! I've added that point as an answer. If you still can't figure out the API connection, you might open a new question (either here or with the library's developer), adding specifics of how you're establishing the connection and what behavior results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your point (2) is what I would consider the correct approach:

```
select Id, Name from Account where Id not in (select AccountId from Contact where Contact.Account_Owner__c = true)
```

The [SOQL and SOSL Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm) that you already found has a lot of details around this anti-join pattern.

The best way to troubleshoot the query is to drop it into the Developer Console. Activate the [Query Plan](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/database_basics_dotnet/units/writing_efficient_queries) tool for performance insights as well. Note that all the standard limits apply, so, for example, you're not going to be able to return more than 50,000 rows.

If the query works in the Developer Console, when you're logged in as the same user that you're connecting as from your script, the likelihood is that the issue lies in the API connection on the script side. If you see different results for different logged-in users, or if one user obtains no results but others do, the issue likely falls in the realm of sharing and visibility. And if the query times out or throws limits errors, you're facing performance and data volume issues.

Each of the above issues would have a different solution path. Luckily, it sounds like you're seeing no more than a connection issue with your script.